# my gradle buildScript don't work

Tags: gradle

1.I am declear my build.gradle on my project rootDir

```
allprojects{
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    group = 'com.gridsum'
    version = '0.1'
}

subprojects{
    apply plugin: 'scala'
    //apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/scalastyle.gradle"
    apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/scoverage.gradle"
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
}



dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.7'
    testCompile 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.11:2.2.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'        
}

}
```

2. declear another buildScript "scoverage.gradle" in gradleDir

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.scoverage:gradle-scoverage:1.0-5-g9c68988'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'scoverage'

ext {
    scalaBinaryVersion = '2.11'
    scoverageVersion = '1.0.2'
}

    dependencies {
        scoverage "org.scoverage:scalac-scoverage-plugin_${scalaBinaryVersion}:${scoverageVersion}",
        "org.scoverage:scalac-scoverage-runtime_${scalaBinaryVersion}:${scoverageVersion}"
}
```

3. It repoert an error "Plguin not found" ,I don't know what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this won't work. `buildScript` block in the script you apply from will not be evaluated. You need to put the `buildScript` block in the script you apply the `scoverage.gradle`. Other way to make it work is to use [init scripts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html).

Comment: two scripts are in different directories. I use : apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/scoverage.gradle"

Comment: It reporter an error : Plguin with id "scoverage" not found。

Comment: @astrisk, see my updated answer. Unfortunately, it will not work this way.